# Find one example : Bijection from $ P=\{A|A\subset N\}, \Omega=\{<x_n>|x_n \in\{0,1\}\} $

Tags: real-analysis

Bijection from $ P=\{A|A\subset N\}, \Omega=\{<x_n>|x_n \in\{0,1\}\} $

I know that both sets are uncountable but I can't come up any example.

Can anyone give me a hint? or solution?

Comment: Can I ask you a question? $\Omega=\{<x_n>|x_n \in\{0,1\}\} $ means the terms of the sequence $<x_n>$ are either 0 or 1?

Comment: That's how I read it, at least.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you!